# How can I use a text editor other than Vim with Git?

Tags: macos, mac, git, textwrangler

I hate Vim, but it seems to be the only program that correctly saves the file and executes a rebase interactive.  Is there any way to use a different editor.  I'd prefer to use a GUI, like Text Wrangler, but I'd use something like Nano, if it would save the file right.

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [git docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#Your-Editor):

> ### Your Editor
>
> You can configure the default text editor that will be used when Git needs you to type in a message. By default, Git uses your system’s default editor, which is generally Vi or Vim. If you want to use a different text editor, such as Emacs, you can do the following:
>
> `$ git config --global core.editor emacs`

Of course since you are like me and want to use a simple text editor for commits and not a text editor that thinks it's an OS, you would use

`$ git config --global core.editor nano`

You can verify your settings with

`$ git config --list`

As for using Text Wrangler I am unfamiliar but the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258538/2437516) seems to be just what youre looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use something similar to this

`git config --global core.editor "'<path to your editor>' <optional arguments like -w for wait if you use sublime text or textmate>"`

I recommend you to read the man page of git-config first.